# how to add pagination to the nested comments in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, recursion, nested-loops

```
class Nested extends Model{
  public function nestedfunc()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Nested::class, 'parent_id');
}
 public function childnestedfunc()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Nested::class, 'parent_id')->with('nestedfunc');
}
}
```

//this is my model function for reccursion.
how to add pagination to the root of the nested comments. i am storing all comments to the same table

1. root comment 1 -nested comments of root 1 ....
2. root comment 2 - nested comments of root 2 ....
3. paginate the root comments
4. root comments 3 - nested comments of root 3 ....
5. root comments 4 -nested commets of root 4.....
6. paginate the root comments
7. so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two separate functions here, relationships can recursively call themselves so first changes your relationships to this

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Nested::class, 'parent_id')->with('children');
}
```

Then for your query you can just do

```
Nested::where('parent_id', null)->with('children')->paginate();
```

When I built a nested comments model I also added a scope to make it a little more readable

```
public function scopeTopLevel($query)
{
   return $query->where('parent_id', null);
}
```

So now the call in my controller is just

```
Comment::topLevel()->with('children')->paginate()
```

Comment: Will it paginate the root level comments. I don't want to paginate the children. Just the root level comments

Comment: Yes, the pagination only applies to the root level comments